# Clear Email Attachment for the next loop

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, email-attachments

I am trying to send attachments to an email list with the following codes. The emails successfully sent but the second email address will get the attachments together with the attachment of the first email address and so for the third email address will get the first and second's attachments.

My question is: Is there any way to clear the attachment before the attachment actually added? I tried to search but no luck.

Please guide me on this, thank you.

```
Set rsInvoices = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE InvMonth = " &  Month(dtPeriod) & " AND InvYear = " & Year(dtPeriod))

selectQuery = "SELECT Email FROM Student WHERE ID = "

On Error GoTo CloseReportHandler

If Not (rsInvoices.EOF And rsInvoices.BOF) Then

    Do Until rsInvoices.EOF = True

        DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, , "Invoice.SID = " & Chr(34) & rsInvoices!SID & Chr(34) & " AND Invoice.InvYear = " & rsInvoices!InvYear & " AND Invoice.InvMonth = " & rsInvoices!InvMonth

        fileName = "Invoice-" & rsInvoices!SID & "-" & rsInvoices!InvYear & "-" & rsInvoices!InvMonth & ".pdf"

        selectQuery = selectQuery + rsInvoices!SID

        Set rsStudents = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Email FROM Student WHERE ID = " & Chr(34) & rsInvoices!SID & Chr(34))

        studEmail = rsStudents!Email

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, path + fileName, False
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Invoice"

        With cdomsg
            .To = studEmail
            .From = "xxx@example.com"
            .subject = "Test Email"
            .TextBody = "Hello"
            .AddAttachment path + fileName
            Set .Configuration = cdoconf
            .Send
        End With

  MoveNextInvoice:
        rsInvoices.MoveNext


    Loop

    Set cdomsg = Nothing
End If

 CloseReportHandler:
    Select Case Err
    Case 2501
        'MsgBox ("here")
        Resume MoveNextInvoice
    Case Else
        MsgBox (Err.Description)
    End Select

Set cdomsg = Nothing
'Kill (path + "*.pdf")
rsInvoices.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of two things:

1. Place an `.Attachments.DeleteAll` statement immediately before the `.AddAttachment` statement, or
2. Create the CDO.Message object (`Set cdomsg = ...`), send it, and `Set cdomessage = Nothing` all inside the `Do Until` loop so you use a fresh CDO.Message object for each iteration.

Comment: I tried your first recommendation and it works! Thank you Gord!